# Can we reuse WebSphere MQ TLS/SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ibm-mq, mq

Let us say, I used a queue manager QMGR1 in host1 to create a CSR and obtain a CA-verified certificate labeled ibmwebspheremqqmgr1. Can I use load the same certificate (and its root and intermediary chains) in another host host2 for the a queue managed named same (i.e. QMGR1) ? In other words, a certreq needs to be present when we 'receive' a certificate using rumqakm or no? Can we just 'add' a cert (like we do the chains)? If the question is not clear, please ask, i can provide more details. In my case host2 is production. host1 is a QA environment where we test connectivity. Thanks.

**Update question from comments 26DEC16**
Specific to MQ, I believe I would have to load CSR first on host2 and then receive the CER again, right? I wonder how do I 'load' the CSR without creating it. I see an option to recreate it in runmqakm, never used that before and not sure if that will work.

Comment: Have a look at this question over at ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/q/481068/349846

Comment: @XSurgent looks good to me. I believe that sorta answered my question. I  can reuse the CSR, CA certified CER on another. Specific to MQ, I believe I would have to load CSR first on host2 and then receive the CER again, right? I wonder how do I 'load' the CSR without creating it. I see an option to recreate it in runmqakm, never used that before and not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes.

When you create a CSR using IBM GSKit (e.g. `runmqakm`), the result is a certificate that is unsigned and the CSR file itself.  The CSR is cryptographically bound to the unsigned certificate that remains in the `.rdb` file of the keystore.  The signed CSR cannot be received into just any keystore at that point.

When you receive the signed CSR, it is combined with the pending unsigned certificate and moved to the `.kbd` file of the keystore.  At this point it is a valid personal certificate with the label name you specified (`ibmwebspheremqqmgr1` in this case) and the DN that you specified.

Once completed you have a usable personal certificate.  If you wanted to use it on another QMgr you would need to get that certificate to that other QMgr in one of two ways:

- Copy the set of files that comprise the keystore.
- Export the personal certificate to a file and then import that file into the other QMgr's keystore.

If you copied the entire keystore and the other QMgr is also named `QMGR1` then you can use them immediately.  If the other QMgr has a different name, then you'd have to rename the certificate to something other than `ibmwebspheremqqmgr1`, or in a modern QMgr set the QMgr's `CERTLABL` attribute to `ibmwebspheremqqmgr1`.  Generally, you want the cert label to reflect the name of the QMgr using it so a QMgr named `QMGR2` with a `CERTLABL` of `ibmwebspheremqqmgr1` is not recommended.

If you import the certificate then you can set the label during the import command.

Keep in mind, the label and the Distinguished Name are two completely different and unrelated things.  The distinguished Name is the value that the CA verified and signed off over and is cryptographically bound tot he keys in the cert.  It is the thing that a remote connection partner decides whether to trust or not.

The label is how the local QMgr or client finds its own certificate.  Imagine you had created two personal certificates, the QMgr needs to know which one to send.  It finds the correct one by matching the label of the certificate to the expected value of `ibmwebspheremq[qmgr name in lower case]` or against the QMgr's `CERTLABL` attribute if it is not blank.

This is why the certificate label can be changed easily with a GSKit command but the Distinguished Name is immutable.

With this in mind, note that external, and many internal, CAs will expect the certificate Common Name of the certificate to contain the fully-qualified hostname where the certificate will be used.  HTTPS clients check that the certificate CN matches the hostname when they connect.  For an MQ connection, this is not the case.  You can put anything in the CN that your CA will sign and use it on a QMgr of any arbitrary name.  So your certificate can have `CN=QMGR1` and that QMgr can live on `mqhost.yourcompany.com` and MQ likes it just fine.  However, *clients using the new MQ REST API will not!*  This is an important distinction for people hoping to use the new MQ REST API.

Finally, please note that best practice is to generate the certificates where they will be used, protect them using filesystem permissions, keep them in local storage, and never copy or move them from that location.  Public/Private key crypto was invented to solve the very difficult problem of securely exchanging private keys.  If the personal certs are copied around it defeats the purpose of using them in the first place.

The various commercial PKI packages (i.e. IBM Tivoli Key Lifecycle Manager, Venafi, etc.) all solve this problem using FIPS-certified algorithms that don't store keys or crypto primitives on disk, securely wipe memory space before releasing it, and in general take excruciating care to not leave keys unprotected in transit, disk or memory.  If you must copy personal certs around, use a real PKI package designed for that purpose if the company has one.  Otherwise, export them to a `.p12` with a very long and random password and avoid email, FTP, or other non-secure means of copying the file around.

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.Rob. You helped me tons in here with MQ questions.

Comment: Glad it helped!